# Can you make a many-to-many field that only selects specific objects from the model

Tags: django, django-models

So I'm currently developing an e-commerce store, where I have a model called OrderItem and a model called Order, the OrderItem contains a BooleanField that tells you whether that item has been ordered or not. The Order contains a many-to-many field to OrderItem to show you what items you have ordered, but the problem is that it also selects the items where ordered=True. Is there any way I can have my many-to-many field only select the items where Ordered=False

Answer (score 0):

You can add limit_choices_to on your model like that:

```
items= models.ManyToManyField(
        to='Item',
        limit_choices_to=~Q(ordered=True),
    )
```

More information on [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)